# How to put allow for two different content types as argument in admin

Tags: django, feincms

I'm a Django and DB noob, but I'm working on a website that has both blogs and articles. They are instantiated in admin in their own respective fields and basically I have a class "`FeaturedPost`" in model.py where for one of the attributes "content" I want to be able to pick from the available blogs or articles.

I'm aware that if I want to map the content to a blog, I would do a

```
models.ForeignKey(Blogs, related_name="w/e")
```

but how do I abstract this so I can pick from the two content types? Would a `GenericForeignKey` be helpful?

I'm using Fein-CMS if that helps with anything in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, [`GenericForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey) is what you need. i.e.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class FeaturedPost(models.Model):
    ...
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    content_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'content_object_id')
```

To edit these in the admin, you'll need to use a [generic inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline)

Comment: Thank you! This will help with what I ultimately need. Now I have to get the actual data from inputs in admin and make it do things.